# clipping a css blured background

Tags: css, webkit

I'm trying to put a CSS3 webkit blur on a background image, and then clip it (by putting it in a smaller parent and setting `overflow: hidden`)

Unfortunately when I do this, my blur effect only takes places on the clipped content, so the edges of my content get visibly "trailed off" from the blur effect (presumably this is some sort of optimization).

example html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child checkerboard"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent {
    width    : 100px;
    height   : 100px;
    position : relative;
    border   : 1px solid #000;
    overflow : hidden;
    margin   : 10px;
}

.child {
    -webkit-filter : blur( 5px );
    width          : 200px;
    height         : 200px;
    position       : absolute;
    top            : -60px;
    left           : -60px;
}

.checkerboard {
    background : url( 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Checkerboard_pattern.svg/220px-Checkerboard_pattern.svg.png' );
}
```

If I use an `<img>` instead of a CSS background, it works as expected ( [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKshH/) )

Unfortunately in my live app I can't easily switch to `<img>` tags so I'm trying to figure out how to get this to work with background images.

Comment: Experimenting, it takes the background of parent and adds that colour as blur on edge.

Comment: @Ruskin -- actually it blurs the child to transparent (which is very noticeable on my actual app since it's over a map and you can see hidden parts through the blur)

Comment: Ah, there was me jumping to conclusions! Interesting problem.

Comment: I cannot see a way around it. Even tried using :before blocks - had same problem. Think you are right about optimisation. Possibly look on chromium / or file a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing why or how, this works (at least in my Chrome):

```
.child {
    -webkit-filter : blur( 5px );
    width          : 200px;
    height         : 200px;
    position       : absolute;
    top            : -60px;
    left           : -60px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/LKshH/1/)

Comment: Works for me too. Good find!

Comment: Nice find, thanks!  :)  `-webkit-transform: anything` kicks the element into hardware acceleration, and there are a whole slew of issues surrounding different elements in mixed rendering modes (GPU accelerated vs non-accelerated items).  So I'm guessing one of two things is happening here: `-webkit-filter` is _not_ GPU accelerated, thus requiring a two-step rendering.  Or it is and `-webkit-transform` is essentially creating a new "stacking context" (whereas blur didn't for some reason).  Either way, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Only way I have got it working is laying an absolutely positioned clipping mask over the top:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sjHEr

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child checkerboard"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class=clip></div>

.clip {
  border:20px solid #FFF;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
}

.parent {
    width    : 100px;
    height   : 100px;
    position : relative;
    border   : 1px solid #000;
    overflow : hidden;
    margin   : 10px;
}

.child {
    -webkit-filter : blur( 5px );
    width          : 200px;
    height         : 200px;
    position       : absolute;
    top            : -60px;
    left           : -60px;
}

.checkerboard {
    background : url( 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Checkerboard_pattern.svg/220px-Checkerboard_pattern.svg.png' );
}
```